# Migrate to a new vdisk

Tags: filesystems, file-copy, storage, san

I have to migrate some data to a new vdisk. But i have no idea how i can do this.

The old Vdisk is under `/dev/mapper/12345` which is a link to `/dev/dm-1`

The new Vdisk is under `/dev/mapper/67890` which is a link to `/dev/dm-2`

There is also a Volume Group with the name `sysvg`.

When i type into the console `dmsetup ls` i get the following output:

```
12345  (253:1)
sysvg-var_tmp_vol       (253:13)
sysvg-var_vol   (253:12)
67890 (253:2)
```

Can someone give me a hint or the solution how i can migrate to thins new vdisk(67890)?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that "/dev/12345" device is part of LVM (VG sysvg):

```
# pvs | grep sysvg
```

You will get something like:

```
# pvs 
  PV         VG        Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree  
  /dev/12345  sysvg lvm2 a--   23.50g   1.44g
  [...]
```

Add new disk to you VG:

```
# vgexteng sysvg /dev/67890
```

Then, move old PV to new PV:

```
# pvmove /dev/12345 /dev/67890
```

Take old PV out of VG

```
# vgreduce sysvg /dev/mapper/12345
```

Delete old disk:

```
# echo 1 > /sys/block/12345/device/delete
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your help But when i type in the pvmove i get the reply that the pysical volume /dev/mapper/12345 not found. Also the /dev/mapper/12345 is not under the sysvg there only is the /dev/mapper/67890 and the /dev/sda2/ Can you tell me what i have forget?

Comment: Could you please, post the output of the command: `pvs`

Comment: PV                                            VG    Fmt   Attr  PSize        PFree
  /dev/mapper/67890                  sysvg lvm2 a--  1020.00m 1020.00m
  /dev/sda2                                 sysvg lvm2 a--   409.10g   68.22g

Comment: And the output of the command: `mount`